# AP Chemistry: Sig Figs Question

Tags: acid-base, significant-figures

This is the official answer of a problem on the AP Chemistry 2009B Exam:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/w9Z4Z3G.png]

The answer has two sig figs, but I think it should have 4 sig figs. I was taught that your end answer should have as many sig figs as that of the number which has the smallest amount that is **used in your calculation.**

When I solved this problem, I used the second approach in the image. The only number I took from the question is 10.93, which has 4 sig figs, so my answer should end up with 4 sig figs.

Is it because 14 has two sig figs? I would think that shouldn't count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read this question, I forgot that the sig figs for pH is different. For pH, the number of sig figs is equal to the number of digits after the decimal.

Since the pH given is 10.93, it has two sig figs (since two digits after decimal) which is the lowest, so the answer should have two sig figs which is does.

Comment: Remark: Linking a [document](http://abacus.bates.edu/acad/depts/biobook/How-SigF.pdf) ("Section E") for further reading on this.